# Visual indication for comment timer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

I ran up against the comment timer and its “Only 1 comment allowed per 15 seconds; timer reset. (click on this box to dismiss)” message and then proceeded to get stuck in the 15 second penalty box loop trying to guess when the coast was clear. It's very easy to get stuck since there's no indication as to when the timer has cleared, and since I have horrible short term memory I tend to try and add my comment before the timer has cleared, therefore continuing my timer hell.

I propose a visual indication, like a textual countdown timer or image, that clearly indicates when you're able to post another comment. The best place for this might be on the actual popup warning so that it doesn't need to clutter any of the site.

Comment: leave your comment ready to post, and go fill your desired liquid container (caffeine optional)

Comment: Soooooooo agree!

Answer (score 5):

I like your idea, but I have a counter offer.

Out loud try this:

```
1 Mississippi,   
2 Mississippi,   
3 Mississippi,   
4 Mississippi,   
5 Mississippi,   
6 Mississippi,   
7 Mississippi,   
8 Mississippi,   
9 Mississippi,   
10 Mississippi,   
11 Mississippi,   
12 Mississippi,   
13 Mississippi,   
14 Mississippi,   
15 Mississippi!
```

*Tap foot twice*

It **always** works like a charm for me ^_^

---

If you want to pace yourself, run this in your browser's console to check how fast you are actually counting, and adjust accordingly:

```
var i = 0; var t = setInterval(function(){
    if(++i === 15) clearInterval(t);
    console.log(i, "seconds");
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Why should I have to bear the burden of counting to 15? That's a lot of numbers you know. Plus, I talk fast.

Comment: @j08691 hence the foot tapping ^_^

Comment: Foot tapping: +1 . Definitely required ;)

Comment: I don't wear socks or shoes at work for just this reason.

Answer (score 2):

If you ask me, I think it's bad design that the timer would be reset. Why not just show the warning and let the timer just keep counting down the original 15 seconds? That would put an end to this timer hell for everyone. Isn't the point of the timer to prevent people from *successfully* posting a second comment within 15 seconds of posting one? The fact that it's not letting you post one within that 15 second window means that it's doing its job. The timer should not have to be reset if the user jumps the gun. That's just plain silly IMHO, and all it does is add unnecessary frustation on the user's part.

Comment: Sooooo agree! Sans crafty, and obnoxious people, if someone were to continue clicking during the countdown, seeing as the timer and blocking are all client side, this will not cause any wasted server time either. No brainer to me, and apparently you also.